# Including xib(s) / nib(s) in a MonoTouch Binding project

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xib, nib

I'm trying to create a re-useable MonoTouch library that contains Views defined in a xib, and Controller code written in Objective-C.

- I have created a static Objective-C library that contains the relevant controller code with all the outlets declared.
  A static *.a library obviously can't contain xib/nib data (if this is possible can someone please let me know), so I can't embed the xibs/nibs in this library.
- I have created a 'MonoTouch Binding Project' that defines the relevant wrapper classes.
  This is where I would ideally also embed the xibs/nibs, and have them included in the app bundle of any final project that links this dll.

Now looking at what a 'MonoTouch Library Project' does with xibs - it compiles it to a nib using ibtool, and then embeds it as a resource in the resultant library dll using the /res option of smcs. I'm assuming this is triggered because the xib file is marked with a "InterfaceDefinition" build action in the project.

However a 'MonoTouch Binding Project' has no "InterfaceDefinition" build action. Is this possible at all using a MonoTouch Binding Project?

I haven't tried it yet, but I'm assuming I could get it working manually by combining what the Library project does with ibtool and smcs /res and what the Binding Project does with btouch and smcs. But I'd rather avoid this, I'm enjoying the lack of Makefiles lately.

Xamarin/MonoTouch team - any plans to add this to Binding Projects in the future? Any way to force it to work currently?

Comment: Please use https://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/149713-monotouch-suggestions so your suggestion does not get lost.

Comment: @poupou Done: http://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/149713-monotouch-suggestions/suggestions/2753378-include-an-interfacedefinition-build-action-for-

Comment: @poupou So is that a no for '_Any way to force it to work currently_'?

Comment: You could compile the xibs to nibs manually then set the build action to EmbeddedResource, and set the resource ID to the mangled format MT library projects use.